# How to append row count to the file name using ssis?

Tags: ssis

I have created a variable called RowCount, used rowcount transformation to store the number of rows retrieved from the source and I am trying to append the row count to the flat file name. But the variable is not saving the rowcount, it always returns 0 my filename is xyz_0 which is not I am looking for. Could some one please help me figuring out the solution for this ?

Comment: you should show us your variables as well as how you are setting that variable in the rowcount transformation and how you are using the variable to append/create the file name.  We can't know what is wrong without details of what your configuration is.  Although you may also determine what the scope of the variable is.  E.g. did you define it in the data flow instead of control flow?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself

Comment: wait so you want to rename the destination flat file connection file name in the middle of the dataflow.  My guess is nothing you do will make that 0 become your count because SSIS more than likley assigns the file name prior to executing the dataflow.  so you would need a way of determining the count prior to the dataflow or dump the dataflow to a recordset determine count and then in another dataflow dump the recordset to the flat file connection........

Answer (score 2):

You can not append the row count value with the filename within the data flow task, as your dynamic flat file connection manager is getting populated before executing the Data Flow Task.

To fix it, use script task or File System task in control flow after the data flow task to rename with row count appended.